# How do I access Mongo DB via Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, mongodb, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, drivers

Does anyone know how do I connect to MongoDB via SQL Developer?
I Have tried to install the third Party JDBC Drivers in SQL Developer for MongoDB but after restarting the SQL Developer I cannot see any options available.

Thanks in advance,
Vassilis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, MongoDB is not a supported migration platform, so we do not support connections to it. We offer connections to 3rd party databases to allow for migrations to Oracle Database.

It's not designed to be a poly-DBMS IDE/GUI.