# how to connect the Mongo DB using sqldeveloper

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, oracle-sqldeveloper

Am using Mongo 4.10 version Please let me know how to connect Mongo DB server from SQL developer (4.1.3) . Using Nosql_connection.

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access Mongo DB via Oracle SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156550/how-do-i-access-mongo-db-via-oracle-sql-developer)

Answer (score 0):

The NoSQL connections in SQL Developer are reserved for the Oracle NoSQL Database. We don't have MongoDB support in Oracle SQL Developer. If and when we do add support for it, it will be for migrating said MongoDB docs over to Oracle Database.